# How can i set the value of a text area with php?

Tags: php, html

I have two issues:-
1.  I need to be able to set the value of a textarea
2.  I need to then get the value of the text area again for updating. I see that text area does not have a 'value' tag or something.. so I am not sure how to do this via PHP. I tried something like

```
print("<textarea cols='15' rows='2' name='textdesc'>$info_desc</textarea>");
```

to set it. But no luck and then i will have the same problem when retrieving.

Comment: What do you mean by "no luck"? That's the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set the value in HTML...

```
<textarea cols="15" rows="2" name="textdesc"><?php echo htmlspecialchars(
    $info_desc, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') ?></textarea>
```

To retrieve it (assuming your form issues a `POST` request)...

```
if (isset($_POST['textdesc'])) {
    $textdesc = $_POST['textdesc'];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

the value of the textarea is within `<textarea>VALUE</textarea>.`

Answer (score 2):

Mayby your variable are undefind?

I try this code and it works correct.

```
$info_desc = "12345";
print("<textarea cols='15' rows='2' name='textdesc'>$info_desc</textarea>");
```

Answer (score 0):

`$info_desc` is actually value of your textarea.
If you submit it, you will get the same value for `$_REQUEST['textdesc']`.