# Populate form text field from database based on dropdown field selection

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, forms

I've dug through many posts but can't find a scenario quite like this on here...

I have a PHP form that contains a dropdown selection containing option values from a MySQL database table. This part works fine. Here's where I need help...

There is a textarea field that I need to populate with data from the same database table, but a different field. This table contains a 'name' and a corresponding set of 'text'. The dropdown shows the 'name' as the options. So what I need is when a selection is made, a script runs (like onChange)... takes the selected value, queries the database to get the 'text' that is associated with the selected 'name'. That 'text' is then displayed inside of the textarea form field.

A section of this code for you to view is:

```
echo "<form action=$PHP_SELF method=\"post\">\n";
echo "<select id=\"conditions\" name=\"conditions\">\n";
echo "<option value=\"Select\" selected>Select a Message</option>\n";

$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM db_scripts");
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
    echo "<option value=".$data->script_id.">".$data->script_name."</option>\n";
}

echo "</select>\n";

echo "<br><textarea name=\"message\" style=\"width:300px; height:130px\" data-maxsize=\"160\" data-output=\"status1\" wrap=\"virtual\" maxlength=\"160\"></textarea><br />\n";
```

So, like I said, this part works just fine. I have the dropdown with the 'script_name' as the options. Now I just need to get the corresponding message into the textarea field "message". Any assistance is most appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118116/how-can-i-set-the-value-of-a-text-area-with-php

Comment: roshan, thanks for that link, but it doesn't help. It's pulling the textarea value from a POST request... but I need the value to come from the select field automatically... BEFORE the form is submitted... so the populated textarea value is included in the form POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have solved this issue... but ended up NOT using any of the other answers. I tried them, particularly the one from Jared. It got me very close, but in the end, did not fully work. I did get some very helpful direction and ideas from Jared though! In the end though, I found a simpler way to get this done...

1) Pulled JQuery in the `<head>` area from Google. No other scripts were loaded there.

2) Put this code in the PHP file above my form, but outside of `<?php>` tags.

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#conditions").change(function() {
    $("#message").val($("#conditions").val());
   })
   $("#conditions").trigger("change");
})
</script>
```

3) Setup the dropdown selection field and textarea target field as...

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM db_scripts");
$first = TRUE; // remove trailing comma from array
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
$html_opts .= "<option value='".preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/', '', strip_tags($data->script_text))."'>".$data->script_name."</option>";   
}
echo '<select id="conditions" name="conditions">';
echo '<option value="" selected>Select a Script</option>';
echo $html_opts.'</select>';
echo '<br><textarea id="message" name="message" style="width:300px; height:130px" data-maxsize="160" data-output="status1" wrap="virtual" maxlength="16\"></textarea><br />';
```

Of course the entire form is not posted here, but the parts that matter are. This is working perfectly for me now. Hopefully it can help someone else too!

Answer (score 2):

Create an associative javascript object literal array in PHP in this format:

```
<?php
echo "
<!-- this script goes in your <head> -->\n
<script>\n
var db_array = [";
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM db_scripts");
$first = TRUE; // remove trailing comma from array
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
  if ($first === TRUE) $first = FALSE;
  else echo ',';
  echo "
  {
    id: '$data->script_id',
    name: '$data->script_name'
    message: '$data->script_message'
  }";
}
echo "];\n
</script>";
?>
```

The catch is that if your message is not in the same row as the id, then you need to use `JOIN` in your query. The idea behind this part is that you're only querying the database once.  You don't want the client to query the database every time they switch an option in the dropdown menu. The exception here is if you have megabytes+ of messages. In this case, consider implementing caching measures.

Moving on... once you have the array constructed, you can build your `<option>`s by iterating through the array like so:

```
<?php
echo "
<form action=\"$PHP_SELF\" method=\"post\">\n
<select id=\"conditions\" name=\"conditions\">\n
<option value=\"Select\" selected>Select a Message</option>\n
<script>\n
for (var i = 0; i < db_array.length; i++) {\n
  document.write('<option value=\"'+db_array[i].id+'\">'+db_array[i].name+'</option>');\n
}\n
</script>\n
</select>\n
<!-- notice the id attribute I added -->\n
<br><textarea id=\"message\" name=\"message\" style=\"width:300px; height:130px\" data-maxsize=\"160\" data-output=\"status1\" wrap=\"virtual\" maxlength=\"160\"></textarea><br />\n";
?>
```

...then have a script with access to these dynamically created DOM elements (e.g. at the end of the `<body>` tag)

```
<script>
// returns the db_array index of the object id supplied
function returnIndex (id) {
  for (var i = 0; i < db_array.length; i++) {
    if (db_array[i].id === id) return i;
  }
  return -1; // returns index of -1 if id is not found
}
// changes the <textarea> message. notice the id I added to the messages <textarea> above
function changeMessage (id) {
  // remember to handle the case of an id not being found within db_array (where returnIndex returns -1)
  document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = db_array[returnIndex(id)].message;
}
// on the event that we switch options, do this event. realize that you'll have to run the changeMessage function once the page loads if you want the first option's message to show
document.getElementById('conditions').onchange = function() {
  changeMessage(this.selectedIndex);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I don't know how to write javascript. How would I modify your javascript code to just loop through establishing the id, name and message... based on how many rows are in that table? Also, yes, the text IS in the same database row as id and name.

Comment: You don't use Javascript to accomplish this. You use the PHP `while` loop you supplied in your code. Notice my random use of `$data` in my code? That wasn't random. Sorry that I wasn't clear on that. I was hoping you would have made the connection between my use of `$data` and your use of `$data`. Do some simple research on the proper construction of a "javascript array of object literals" and it should be pretty intuitive on how to construct one with the use of your `while` loop.

Comment: I'll elaborate on my use of 'intuitive.' Notice how you construct multiple `<option>` tags within your `while` loop which you ultimately put within a `<select>` tag? The concept for my code is similar in that you are constructing multiple 'javascript object literals' that you will ultimately put/`push` within a 'javascript array.'

Comment: I buckled in and wrote it for you. :)

Comment: I also put the html form within php echos like you supplied them in your question.

Comment: thanks again for your help! We are getting closer here. Problem is that the script you gave in the first section starting with `var db_array = [` is actually displaying in my form. Plus, my select field is not getting the `<option>`s created like they were before. I see data being pulled from the database and displayed onscreen, giving the id, name, message, etc. Not sure why it's displaying like it is. Also, I'm getting a ReferenceError db_array is not defined. Sorry... I'm feeling like an idiot. :)

Comment: That's because javascript goes within `<script></script>` tags just like php goes within `<?php ?>` tags. I fixed my answer.

Comment: I had to correct a couple of things in your code example, but I'm loading now with just one error...

`ReferenceError: script_array is not defined
 
for (var i = 0; i < script_array.length; i++) `

My dropdown field is not populating with anything at this point though.

Comment: If that error came from the code I gave you, you renamed `db_array` to `script_array` somehow.

Comment: Yes I renamed it in all references. That's not the problem. Error was there either way. Still, solution never worked fully for me. I posted a solution that I was able to get the job done and working. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is set the form action to `GET`.
Then if a `conditions` query parameter is set select the corresponding text from the database and show it is the `textarea`. So using `PDO`s

```
$text = "";
if(isset($_GET["conditions"])){
    $db->prepare("
        SELECT text
        FROM db_scripts
        WHERE script_name = ?
    ");

    $stmt->bindColumn(1, $type);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    if(!empty($row)){
        $text = htmlentities($row["text"]);
    }
);


echo "</form><textarea name=\"message\" style=\"width:300px; height:130px\" data-maxsize=\"160\" data-output=\"status1\" wrap=\"virtual\" maxlength=\"160\">$text</textarea><br />\n";
```

Comment: FYI> The poster is missing an <input> for the submit button within his form.

Comment: Conaire - I can not use GET for this... must remain POST. Suggestions? How do I pull the script_name for my query?

Andrew - I'm well aware that the entire form is not posted above. The form is working so I didn't need a full evaluation of the entire form. I only posted the part that is applicable to my question. Thanks!

Comment: You could leave the the form as POST and it would still work.

Comment: Conaire, this is close, but not quite. I need the textarea value to come from the select field automatically... BEFORE the form is submitted... so the populated textarea value is included in the form POST.

Comment: @N8Dog If you want to do this you'll have to use javascript, see above. Do you want the text to appear in the `textarea` so the user can see it or why?

Comment: See above... as in the other answer? To answer your question, this is being used for someone to select a message from a list of options, then the full text of the message display in the textarea box... so then when the form is submitted, that message is actually sent out via text message. Basically a tool to send out pre-written messages.